# How to use string in place of url in image source

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to embed an image in a div. The source of the image is dynamic which is stored in the attribute 'weatherIconURL' of the JS Object 'storeLocations'. That is for each storeLocation I am trying to show the corresponding weatherIcon image. Below is the code I am using

```
var block = '<div>'+'<p><b>'+storeLocations[i].accountName+'</b></p>'+
                             '<p>Min Temp: '+storeLocations[i].minTemp+'</p>'+
                             '<p>Max Temp: '+storeLocations[i].maxTemp+'</p>'+
                             '<img src="storeLocations[i].weatherIconURL"/>'+
                        '</div>';
```

The image is not getting displayed. I have tried using escape character as well.

Comment: `'<img src="' + storeLocations[i].weatherIconURL + '"/>'+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including the variable in the string the same way you are all the others. Notice the difference? This should fix you up:

```
var block = '<div>'+'<p><b>'+storeLocations[i].accountName+'</b></p>'+
            '<p>Min Temp: '+storeLocations[i].minTemp+'</p>'+
            '<p>Max Temp: '+storeLocations[i].maxTemp+'</p>'+
            '<img src="' + storeLocations[i].weatherIconURL + '"/>'+
            '</div>';
```

Syntax highlighting (like that used here on SO) should make this stand out to a simple visual inspection.

Answer (score 0):

why are you using concatinate so much simply add this code

```
var block = '<div><p><b>'+storeLocations[i].accountName+'</b></p><p>Min Temp: '+storeLocations[i].minTemp+'</p><p>Max Temp: '+storeLocations[i].maxTemp+'</p><img src='+storeLocations[i].weatherIconURL+'/></div>';
```

Comment: perhaps to make it easier to read?